# Get current song name, for a local application

Tags: spotify

I want to get the current song name that is being played by spotify desktop. Is there any api for doing this?

Optimally I would like something like:

```
string song = spotify.GetSong();
```

in c++ or c#. I can only seem to find the old libspotify api although it seems to no longer be a usable.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can do it via the API, but I use the following code to return spotifys window title (Artist - Track)

```
public string GetSpotifyTrackInfo()
    {
        var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify").FirstOrDefault(p =>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.MainWindowTitle));

        if (proc == null)
        {
            return "Spotify is not running!";
        }

        if (string.Equals(proc.MainWindowTitle, "Spotify", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return "Paused";
        }
        return proc.MainWindowTitle;
    }
```

Comment: thx mate, after few tweaks and making return value object instead of string, this is perfect for my project